# RhoMobile Objective C Client 64bit Build Fail

Tags: ios, ipad, rhomobile, rhodes, rhoconnect

I am facing a problem in RhoSync. Recently the Apple announced that they are no longer going to support 32bit application from now onwards. I updated the project to build for 64bit architectures, but is facing the following problem:
No viable overloaded 'operator->' in INetRequest.cpp.

Earlier I got a 3 errors in the CURL library being used by the project. I updated the library and the error successfully went away.

[image: RhoSync Project error]

Any help will be appreciated.